# Добавление записей в таблицу

Tags: php, javascript, html

На странице есть таблица с ордерами, которая в html заполнена данным образом

```html
<div class="orders__table-row">
  <div class="orders__table-pair">****</div>
  <div class="orders__table-buy">BUY</div>
  <div class="orders__table-amount">1111</div>
  <div class="orders__table-price">11111<span></span></div>
  <div class="orders__table-time">11111</div>
  <div class="orders__table-status orders__table-status--cancelled">cancelled</div>
  <div class="orders__table-close">
    <img src="img/icons/orders__close.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Так же есть форма с полями для заполнения и кнопкой. Как сделать, чтобы после заполнения полей и нажатия кнопки, новый ордер добавился в таблицу?

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу только кучу дивов не несущих никакой смысловой нагрузки, имеющих тонну разных классов (почитайте о том, зачем нужны классы и идентификаторы).

Форма делается примерно таким образом

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Ваш возраст: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Где action.php - название скрипта для обработки, а method - это собственно метод передачи (тут копетан был). Далее вы уже обрабатываете данные из переменной (в данном случае POST).
Вот так

```
$_POST['age'];
```

Где в кавычках атрибут name из формы. А обилие дивов в вашем коде пугает.
Собственно ссылка на подробное описание

> http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php

Далее вы уже в скрипте должны запись в БД делать (если под таблицой вы подразумевали таблицу в БД, ибо это понятно по метке php).

Comment: C этими вещами знаком, как добавлять данные в таблицу БД я знаю, мне нужно заполнить таблицу, которая находится на самой странице, т.е чтоб при нажатии кнопки, в в мою структуру(таблицу на странице) добавлялись новые записи

Comment: Отсылайте запрос на добавление данных в таблицу Аяксом, и в success (если добавление в базу успешно) добавьте в свою таблицу c помощью `jQuery` и метода `obj.append("");`